# Dart Markdown package, how to handle new lines

Tags: dart, markdown, angular-dart

I am trying to make a WYSIWYG internal tool. And we decided to implement this feature with contentEditable. However, we save data to our databases in markdown. So I have to be able to parse from html to md and back. For html to md I use package html2md and for the other way around I use Markdown package.

The issue i've been having is that when you write to my editor text like

```
HEY



After many lines some text
```

It produces this in md

```
HEY







After many lines some text
```

Notably it uses 2 whitespace and 2 LF characters (or atleast i think so but i might be slightly wrong.) I solved this issue by parsing it like this

```
markdownToHtml(data.replaceAll('&', '&amp;').replaceAll('<', '&lt;').replaceAll('>', '&gt;'), inlineSyntaxes: [TextSyntax(String.fromCharCodes([32,32,10,10]),sub: "<div><br></div>")],inlineOnly: true );
```

The inline only parameter was neccesary because without it the text syntax wasnt applied for some reason. However this inline only then bit me in the arse when I tried to implement parsing of unordered lists, which are parsed as blocks. So I need a way to correctly parse these empty lines without using inline only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class EmptyLineBlockSyntax extends BlockSyntax{
  RegExp get pattern => RegExp(r'^(?:[ \t][ \t]+)$');

  const EmptyLineBlockSyntax();

  Node parse(BlockParser parser) {
    parser.encounteredBlankLine = true;
    parser.advance();

    return Element('p',[Element.empty('br')]);
  }
}

return markdownToHtml(data.replaceAll('&', '&amp;').replaceAll('<', '&lt;').replaceAll('>', '&gt;'),  blockSyntaxes: [EmptyLineBlockSyntax()]);
```